# Have AT LEAST one and not another query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a bit stumped on a query. I have two tables Clients & Payment.

| Clients | Client_Status |
| --- | --- |
| ao16g0000fh35AAe | Active |
| ao16g0000fh35BAe | Canceled |

| Payment_ID | Client_ID | Payment_Type | Schedule_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a076g00000FGzasAAD | ao16g0000fh35AAe | Draft Payment | 5/13/2021 |
| a076g00000FEn9DAAT | ao16g0000fh35AAe | Admin Fee | 5/13/2021 |
| a076g00000FEn9CAAT | ao16g0000fh35AAe | Service Fee | 5/13/2021 |

I am looking to write a query that will provide me with a count of clients that are ACTIVE and have at least one 'Admin Fee' payment_type but do NOT have a 'Service Fee' payment_type.

Within the example I'm displaying a client that has all three payment types but there can however be clients that will have Draft Payments and Admin Fee but not a Service Type or vice versa.

```
SELECT count(c.client_id)
FROM "Client" c
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.client_id
FROM "Payment" p
WHERE p.payment_type like 'Admin Fee'
GROUP BY p.client_id) as p on c.client_id = p.client_id
WHERE c.client_status like 'Active'
```

Above is what I currently have which provides me with a count of clients that have a payment type of admin fee that are active but now I need to find a count of clients that are active and have a payment type of Admin Fee but DO NOT have service fee as a payment type.

Comment: Your sample data is lacking in variety to clearly demonstrate your requirement and you neglect to actually show your desired result - your sample data can only have a maximum count of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables, group by client, filter only active clients and set the conditions for the payment_type in the HAVING clause.
Then use `COUNT()` window function to get the number of clients:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () number_of_clients
FROM Client c INNER JOIN Payment p 
ON c.client_id = p.client_id
WHERE c.client_status = 'Active'
GROUP BY c.client_id
HAVING SUM((p.payment_type = 'Admin Fee')::int) > 0
   AND SUM((p.payment_type = 'Service Fee')::int) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count distinct` and `not exists`

```
select count(distinct p.Client_ID) cnt_AdminNoService
from Payment p
where p.Payment_Type = 'Admin Fee'
   and not exists (
        select 1
        from Payment p2
        where p2.Client_ID = p.Client_ID and p2.Payment_Type = 'Service Fee')
```